# Why `sqlpp-mysql` is not properlly linking?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, c++11, linker

I am trying to establish database connection using [sqlpp-connector-mysql](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11-connector-mysql). After building this project when i am trying to run `SampleTest.cpp` it produce error saying

```
$ g++ -std=c++1y -lsqlpp-mysql SampleTest.cpp

SampleTest.cpp:(.text+0x12f): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::connection(std::shared_ptr<sqlpp::mysql::connection_config> const&)'
SampleTest.cpp:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::~connection()'
SampleTest.cpp:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::connection(std::shared_ptr<sqlpp::mysql::connection_config> const&)'
SampleTest.cpp:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::execute(std::string const&)'
SampleTest.cpp:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::execute(std::string const&)'
SampleTest.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::execute(std::string const&)'
SampleTest.cpp:(.text+0x2c9): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::execute(std::string const&)'
```

I think, `sqlpp-mysql` is not linking properly. Can someone give me some pointer, how to resolve this problem ?

P.S : I have build the requirements.

- [sqlpp11](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11)
- [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)

I build the both `sqlpp11` and `sqlpp11-connector-mysql` like this

```
$ cd project_dir
$ cmake CmakeList.txt
$ sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to link the library properly.

```
g++ -std=c++11 tests/SampleTest.cpp -I ../../sqlpp11/include -I . -I ../../date -lsqlpp-mysql -lmysqlclient
```